# IBM Worklight - "config.xml is malformed xml or could not be found in the application's root"

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, ripple

While compiling my application, developed as a Worklight 5.0.6.1 Hybrid application with the BlackBerry 6/7 environment, I get the following warning message:

> config.xml is malformed xml or could not be found in the application's root.

Comment: Please edit your question with the version of Worklight, and the fact that you're actually referring to BlackBerry, and also which BlackBerry OS version... we are not mind readers, as much as we'd like to be.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your .cod file is being generated and you manage to successfully install it and the    application functions with no issues, I suggest to ignore this warning message. I have yet to see it harm a Worklight application in any way.

Comment: but the same warning message for android for 2.3 or 3.1 and it causes the unexpected termination of the application...is there any solution for that...??

Comment: You're not explaining your question good enough - where do you get this for Android? Edit your question with more information.

Comment: Whenever i tried to develope an android application for 2.3 or 3.1 platform and tried to compile and run it on AVD it throws an exception and the application terminates unexpectedly, but the same application runs properly to my blackberry. I can't understand the reason of that, if you need logcat for that plz tell me.

Comment: Google has a bug in the Android 2.3 Emulator; no application with a webview (like a Worklight app...) will work there. Use an AVD with Android 2.2 or 4.

Comment: but the same problem remains when i tried to run those application on my real device runing android 2.3.6 ?

Comment: Listen, you are really thin on details. EDIT your question with all of your problem and all logs you get when the problem(s) happen. I can't help you when you're only giving me bits of new information with each comment.